# Open a file directly from a directory path window

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I would like to , when I click a button that opens a file directory, the user selects a file (a shapefile for example) and once the user clicks OK, that the selected shapefile is opened with ArcGis.

I have no idea how to do this with PyQt.. I guess I have to start with something like this :

> activ = str(QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.button, Select File', pathDir, ' '))

But I don't see how I can then open the file.

Answer (score 0):

Since now `activ` contain the file name (and path), if you are trying to call an external program you can use the subprocess module with something like

```
subprocess.call([executable, activ])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Eventually I used os.system(activ) and it works.

I will try your method as well.